# Stronger speaker for iPhone 4, is it possible to buy?

Tags: iphone, speakers

My speaker on my iPhone 4 is not as strong as I want it to be, I am not hearing it well when someone calls me - the ringtone is too quiet. It is set to maximum, but still too quiet for my taste. Is there a 3rd party seller that has a stronger speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is nothing like that available. While it is possible to make a louder speaker, I believe iOS sets the volume limit itself, though I couldn't be sure.

I would imagine if a mod like that were possible, the speaker would need to connect to the headphone jack internally in order to bypass iOS's limit.

It's really all just speculation, though.